# Segmentation fault backtracked to vfprintf?

Tags: c, file-io, gdb, segmentation-fault

I get a segmentation fault and using gdb and backtrace, it is thrown at vprintf.

```
#0  0x006e8779 in vfprintf () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x006f265f in fprintf () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x08049fd1 in write_tofile (logfile=0x9843090 "~/www/log") at example.c:446
```

It happens when I call

```
file = fopen(log_file, "a"); // log_file = "~/www/log"
fprintf(file, buffer);
```

Can fopen handle files from different directories? Would anyone have a clue as to why it segfaults here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using '`~`' as an abbreviation for your home directory is a shell thing, and isn't necessarily available in C. This is likely to cause the `fopen` to fail, and you're not checking the return code.

Answer (score 2):

You must *never* fail to check for errors in operations that aren't 100% under your control. If you don't know whether a file exists and the open operation must succeed (and that's something you really cannot know for sure, ever), you must test:

```
FILE * f = fopen(log_file, "a");

if (!f) { /*error, die? */ }

fprintf(f, buffer);
```

Also make sure that `buffer` is a valid pointer to the first character of a null-terminated array of characters, and that the string doesn't contain any format specifiers.

For just printing a raw string `str`, it is safer to use `fputs(str, f)`, or `fprintf(f, "%s", str)` if you must.

Answer (score 0):

Check the contents of buffer. You have either a unescaped % symbol and/or no null terminating character.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably `fopen` failed & returned a `NULL` pointer.

You should check the return value of `fopen` before using it, and use `errno` to determine what the error was.